# User logged-in from front end is logged out automatically accessing wp-admin

Tags: uploads, buddypress

I have stuck in serious problem. I want to create a document and upload a word doc from front end after user login. Logged in user is admin. The plugin bp-doc uses WordPress default media uploader to upload file.

The plugin hits `.../wp-admin/async-upload.php`, but this throws an error `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later`, after debuging in console I found `302 Moved Temporarily` error and in response there is WordPress login form.

After doing some research I found another error, when I log in from frontend as an admin and goes back to `wp-admin` it logged me out and asks again to enter username and password.

I unable to go through the errors, anyone can help me what may goes wrong?

I uses the following code to login

```
$user_data = array();
$user_data['user_login'] = $username;
$user_data['user_password'] = $password;
$user_data['remember'] = $remember; 

$user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {

$err = "<strong>ERROR!</strong> Invalid username or password";

} 
else {

  wp_set_current_user( $user->ID);

  do_action('set_current_user');
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $redirect_to = home_url().'/members/'.$current_user->user_login.'/profile'; 
  wp_redirect($redirect_to);
  exit;
}
```

Live site url: https://www.group50.com/g50consultants

Answer (score 2):

have you tried by setting the second argument of `wp_signon()` to `true` or blank?
set false will prevent `wp_signon()` from setting secure cookie which is essential for accessing `wp-admin` if your using ssl.
i have tested and `$user = wp_signon( $user_data, true );` works as expected.

Comment: Sorry. The post is too old and currently I don't have access to that project. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: for some reason i found this question on the top, so i answer it :)

Comment: I'm facing this issue and none of your solution is solving it

Comment: The answer dated 2017-01-10, WordPress core updated a lot, you might want to enable WP_DEBUB, and take a look if anything interesting int the debug.log file also you might need to post a new question with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your switching from https to http after login, you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/ to redirect all your site to https, I used it once and also changed my site URL from http://... to https://.... in wodpress settings.

I see that you can simplify your code in these lines:

```
else {
  $redirect_to = home_url().'/members/'.$user->user_login.'/profile'; 
  wp_redirect($redirect_to);
  exit;
}
```

Beacuse the wp_signon function create all the sessions and fill the current user functions.